# MySQL/MariaDB data directory backup

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, mariadb

I am using a solution of [backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/) / [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) / [duply](http://duply.net/) to create backups of my databases. I upload full backups and incremental backups to B2 using duplicity via duply. The incrementals are done similar to rsync.

My server is 100GB and my databases are currently 70GB, but I don't suspect them to grow much. I dont have a master/slave setup. I want a backup solution that allows me to backup the 70GB of databases but not require very much space during the backup process.

I decided that I could just backup the whole `/var/lib/mysql` directory instead of using `mysqldump` or other backup methods which requires a full backup persist on disk.

I read that in order to do this method I would have to completely turn off the mysql server, do the backup, and turn it back on. I am OK with that because duplicity does incremental backups which should only take a few minutes.

I have ran `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;` in order to make shutdown/starup as fast as can be and verified via `show global status like '%dirty%';` that `Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty` hovers around 0.

I also understand the caveat for InnoDB tables is that they require the exact same mysql version in order to properly restore. Is that still the case?

Is there anything I am missing and will I have a near 100% confidence that if I use the exact mysql version (mariadb in my case) that at least one of my hundreds of incremental backups will restore.

Answer (score 0):

How does duplicity do the "incremental" backups?  By doing something like rsync?  Or using MySQL's binlogs?

One of the least invasive backups involves LVM.

- About 1 minute of downtime, *regardless* of dataset size.
- Only a few percent of disk space needed, *regardless* of dataset size.  (10% might be more than generous.)
- And, yet, you always get a *full* backup.

How, you should ask?  Obviously some kind of sleight of hand.  Hint: a COW is involved.

But, alas, you have to plan ahead and set up a "Logical Volume" for this to work with.  And the OS has to provide such.  Here's how it works:

1. Set up the LV (one-time task)
2. when you want to take a dump, do the following steps:
3. stop mysqld
4. take a "snapshot" of the entire disk (perhaps 1 minute)
5. start mysqld
6. *now* you get the slow tedious task of copying the entire snapshot to somewhere else.

More info on the LV and the snapshot in the LV:

- The snapshot is a "logical" copy of all the disk blocks.
- It feels like a separate drive.
- It takes very little extra space -- to start with
- When *either* drive writes anything, the COW mooves into help.  COW = Copy On Write.  That is, the block that is being modified now needs to be come two blocks (and takes more *real* disk space).  One drive keeps the old copy; one gets the new.
- During your copy to elsewhere, the backup LV drive still sees only "old" blocks.
- During your copy, mysqld continues to modify blocks, oblivious to the COW grazing in the background.
- Well, there will be a lot of I/O due to the copy.

Other notes...

- Yes, it would be better to have exactly the same version.
- You could install a newer version with the backup, but be sure to do `mysql_upgrade`.  You could even test an upgrade right there in the snapshot -- without copying to elsewhere.  (Note: the LV would need to be big enough for whatever changes in it.)
- There is no concept of "incremental" (unless your copy is something like rsync).
- Because I suggested actually stopping mysqld, there is no hard need for playing with %dirty%, etc.  After all, InnoDB can recover from a power failure; this is more graceful than that.

Comment: The server is a VPS so LVM isn't very viable. Yes duplicity ( http://duplicity.nongnu.org/  ) is something like rsync. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have 100% confidence that the backups are working is to test them regularly.

How busy is this server? Doing the backups from the secondary server, is generally a good way to keep the primary performant. Maybe you don't have that concern though.